# Python: How to grab and update values from another program?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Right, now what I made was a little alarm.

Firstly, it gets a value from the user. This value is set as a limit.

Secondly, a second value is entered and then checked to see if it exceeds the 'limit' value, if it does, it rings an alarm in a loop until the program is closed. Else, it asks for the value again and then rechecks it.

That's all very nice. But the actual intent here was to get it to stream values or have them update every half second. (I can do the timing) from another program that would be running at the same time.

I decided to choose Core Temp, it's got this plugin that apparently acts as a server and can be asked for status information from the CPU.

I was told my task is simple, (Asked once on a Google Group, they never got back after this)

I was told to

> write a little function or class 
>   that opens a network socket, connects to that plugin and asks it for the 
>   information you require.

I then need to find out what network protocol this plugin uses to communicate.

Can someone please tell me exactly how to do this? And explain the steps and the modules or 'functions'(?) I may be using?

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
print("\t\tTemperature Alarm\n\n")
print("Please enter the value at which the temperature\n should not exceed\n")
try:
    Limit = int(input("\nLimit: "))
except ValueError:
    print("You must have not entered a numerical value, please do so\n or the program will close")
    Limit = int(input("\nLimit: "))
xvalue = int(input("Enter a test value to test if it works: "))

while xvalue < Limit:
    xvalue = int(input("Update please: "))
else:
    while True:
        print("Temperature exceeded by:",xvalue-Limit,"units")
        print("\a")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I did, but I can't get the darn code to enter as code in the edit page. I tried 5 times then gave up. I can upload an image

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) on how to format code blocks.

Comment: Can't add image, not enough rep. I'll check that out now.

Comment: Already formatted your code for you. Often, people will happily inline images when you insert the link into your post.

Comment: inline images? Thanks for that, I was wondering why it suddenly fixed itself!

Comment: 'inline': replace the plain URL with the image in your post. For code, images are actually a really bad idea, since noone can copy it then and try it out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at ZeroMQ. It is a messaging library able to interface programs written in a multitude of languages with eachother.

http://www.zeromq.org/